# why is there a color palette table after the header in bitmap's

Tags: bitmap

Why can bitmaps with pixel depth higher than 8 bit can do without a color table and the ones with 8 bit and below require a color palette table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because bitmaps with a pixel depth of 8 bits and lower do not necessarily use a fixed color table. Instead, they define a custom optimized 8-bit color table that contains only the specific colors used in that particular bitmap image. In other words, they use a "selective" palette.

Remember that bitmaps are indexed images, which means that the color of each pixel is defined by an integer value that specifies an index into the color palette.

The advantage is that on systems with very limited color display capabilities, the bitmap's color palette can be optimized for those specific colors that the bitmap uses, rather than some generic list of colors.

For comparison purposes, here are two sample images. Both of them use only an 8-bit color palette, but the one on the left uses an optimized (or "selective") color palette, while the one on the right was forced into conformity with the standard Windows 256-color palette:

[image: Lena 8-bit (optimized)]                         [image: Lena 8-bit (non-optimized)]

The difference in quality and color fidelity is immediately clear. The one on the left is *far* superior, even with the same 8 bits per pixel to play with.

Once you get above 8 bits per pixel, this isn't very important. The "standard" or "generic" colors give you plenty to work with to produce a recognizable image. That's not so with only 256 colors, much less 16.

Comment: So when you enrich 8 bit images does it actually modify the color pallete and not the bitmap data ?

Comment: @klijo: I'm not sure what you mean by "enriching" the images. This is generally done when saving the bitmap file. The color palette is selected based on the colors used in the image. The color palette is only updated when the bitmap is saved.

Comment: OK so lets say you change the color at a certain pixel. If that new color is not there in the color palette then the palette is updated and if the color is there in the palette then the pixel value is updated. Am i correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Because the 4/8 bit values are an index into a 16/256 entry colour table, whereas with 24-bits the values are specifying the actual intensity of the Reg, Green, and Blue components of each pixel.