# Win32 BITMAPINFO how to reliably allocate enough memory for RGBQUAD array / color table (bmiColors field)?

Tags: winapi, colors, bitmap

I have a `HBITMAP` and I want to get the full `BITMAPINFO` structure from that `HBITMAP` with corresponding `RGBQUAD` array, not just `BITMAPINFOHEADER`.

This is the structure of `BITMAPINFO`:

```
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFO {
  BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader;
  RGBQUAD          bmiColors[1];
} BITMAPINFO, *LPBITMAPINFO, *PBITMAPINFO;
```

I can use `GetDIBits` with `NULL` pointer for reference to the bit buffer to get **just** the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` into my allocated `BITMAPINFO` memory.

What I don't know, is how to **reliably** calculate size of `RGBQUAD` array from that `BITMAPINFOHEADER` data so that I can allocate enough space to allow `GetDIBits` to store that whole array as well. Documentation (and many code samples I've found) is very confusing and it's even conflicting on some parts regarding this topic.

Comment: [*"The number of entries in the array depends on the values of the `biBitCount` and `biClrUsed` members of the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` structure."*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfo) => [description of `biBitCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd183376(v=vs.85)) documents this fully.

Comment: @GSerg it does not document this fully. Depends how? They explain various different cases, but as I've mentioned in different places in the documentation they have contradictory information. In some places they say only bitmaps with 8 bits of depth and below have color tables, on other places they say it's everything below 24. My main problem is that I can't get a clear answer from the documentation. Or the one I can understand.

Comment: Because bitmaps with a pixel depth of 8 bits and lower do not necessarily use a fixed color table. Instead, they define a custom optimized 8-bit color table that contains only the specific colors used in that particular bitmap image. In other words, they use a "selective" palette. Refer: [why is there a color palette table after the header in bitmap's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574896/why-is-there-a-color-palette-table-after-the-header-in-bitmaps)

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT yes, I understand that they put colors into an "indexed" table and just reference them, problem is that documentation / standard is not clear about other depths and how to calculate table size for them (or how to know if bitmap even has a color table). Can you take a look at my answer and see if you can spot any obvious flaws? It works for now, but I'm not sure about all edge cases. It's weird that API doesn't provide a function to just return size of related color table from `HBITMAP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After re reading documentation, wiki, some blog posts and other sources (none of which are internally consistent) this seems like the best way to determine number of elements in Color Table (RGBQUAD array):

Use `GetDIBits` with `NULL` value for pixel buffer to get `BITMAPINFO`:

```
BITMAPINFO* pbinfo = ( BITMAPINFO* ) malloc( sizeof( BITMAPINFOHEADER ) );
...
pbinfo->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof( BITMAPINFOHEADER );
GetDIBits( hScreenMemory, hBitmap, 0, 0, NULL, pbinfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS );
```

And then based on the:

1. `pbinfo->bmiHeader.biBitCount`
2. `pbinfo->bmiHeader.biClrUsed`
3. `pbinfo->bmiHeader.biCompression`

we can determine number of `RGBQUAD` array elements with the following logic:

```
DWORD ColorTableLength( BITMAPINFOHEADER* h ) {
  DWORD result        = 0;

  DWORD biClrUsed     = h->biClrUsed;
  WORD  biBitCount    = h->biBitCount;
  DWORD biCompression = h->biCompression;

  switch ( biBitCount ) {
    case 24:
      result = biClrUsed;
      break;
    case 16:
    case 32:
      if ( biCompression == BI_RGB )
        result = biClrUsed;
      else if ( biCompression == BI_BITFIELDS )
        result = 3;
      break;
    default: // for 0, 1, 2, 4, and 8
      if ( biClrUsed == 0 )
        result = ( 1 << biBitCount ); // 2^biBitCount
      else
        result = biClrUsed;
      break;
  }

  return result;
}
```

This is the "lowest common denominator" which is consistent between many resources and examples that I've found online (and there's still possibility that it'll not work for every case).

Number of bytes that need to be allocated for `RGBQUAD` array can be calculated by `sizeof(RGBQUAD) * ColorTableLength( &... )`.

In some cases `RGBQUAD` array is replaced by 3 `DWORD`s, but sizes of `DWORD` and `RGBQUAD` are the same so it doesn't matter which `sizeof` we multiply with `ColorTableLength` value.

I'm not sure why the standard doesn't define a field which explicitly states how many bytes are reserved for Color Table / `RGBQUAD` array / RGB `DWORD`s but that's the way it is it seems.

`biClrUsed` field supposedly has that purpose but not in all cases.